# Is there an English translation of the Parisian Alfonsine tables

Tags: coordinate, ephemeris

I'm interested in the Alfonsine tables published in Paris in the 1400s. I know there is an English translation of what survived of earlier Alfonsine tables from Castile, but that's not what I'm interested in. If you know of software that implements the algorithms implied by the table, that would be good too.

Comment: Can you maybe provide links?

Comment: Link to book review of what I'm NOT interested: http://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/2004JHA....35..479S A link to the Latin version is https://books.google.com/books?id=4ppKAAAAcAAJ

Comment: Something to think about; there is also a History of Science and Mathematics Stack Exchange: http://hsm.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Couldn't get it working myself (didn't try very hard), but AlfonsoTab.XLS on http://home.thep.lu.se/~larsg/Site/download.html may be helpful